# backbone.js how to create static method in model?

Tags: backbone.js

For Example I have the following code

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    foo: function(){
       console.log('in foo..')
    }
});
```

This `foo` method works if I instantiate `myModel` but is there any way to access it without instantiating ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass it as the second argument to `extend`:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend(
    // instance properties
    {
        foo: function() {
           console.log('in foo..')
        }
    },
    // static
    {
        bar: function() {
           console.log('in bar..')
        }
    }
);
```

Here, `foo` will be available only in instances of `myModel`, and `bar` can be called statically. `myModel.bar()`.

Comment: Phew..Didn't expect its that simple :)

Comment: Didn't know backbone made statics so straight forward. +1

Comment: @Bosworth99: The documentation even says [`Backbone.Model.extend(properties, [classProperties]) `](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend) so this really shouldn't be a mystery.

Comment: How can I define the classproperties in coffeescript?